# Date field displayed in unexpected format in Laravel MSSQL and Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel application with MSSQL as the database backend With Ubuntu 18.04.6 OS. I have date fields named **effect_from** and **effect_to** in one of my models. However, when I retrieve the model's attributes, the effect_from date field is displayed in an unexpected format.

Here's an example of the retrieved attributes:

```
#attributes: array:12 [
"id" => 3465
"employee_shift_master_id" => 231
"employee_id" => "832"
"created_at" => "2023-06-12 11:02:41"
"updated_at" => "2023-06-12 11:02:41"
"deleted_at" => null
"employee_company_info_id" => 343
"effect_from" => "Jun 13 2023 12:00:00:AM"
"effect_to" => "Jun 30 2023 12:00:00:AM"
"created_by" => 481
"updated_by" => null
"deleted_by" => null
```

]

The **effect_from** field is expected to be in the format "Y-m-d", but it's being displayed as **"Jun 13 2023 12:00:00:AM"**. This unexpected format is causing issues when working with the date field in my application.

I have checked the database table and confirmed that the **effect_from** field is stored in the correct format. I also verified that the column type in the MSSQL database is date.

**Table:-**
[image]

**Model:-**

```
namespace Modules\HR\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HrEmployeesInShift extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'employee_shift_master_id'
      ,'employee_id'
      ,'created_at'
      ,'updated_at'
      ,'deleted_at'
      ,'employee_company_info_id'
      ,'effect_from'
      ,'effect_to'
      ,'created_by'
      ,'updated_by'
      ,'deleted_by'
    ];


    public function employeeDetails()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(HrEmployeeCompanyInfo::class,'employee_id','employee_id');
    }
    public function employeesShiftMaster()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(HrEmployeeShiftMaster::class,'employee_shift_master_id','id');
    }

}
```

**Query:-**

```
$data = HrEmployeesInShift::with('HrEmployeeShiftMaster')->where('status',1)->where('deleted_at',NULL)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

If Iam using **FORMAT(effect_from,'yyyy-MM-dd')** method it will work. But I don't want to do the format. Because it is difficult to change my all other code and relationships

**Formatted Query:-**

```
$data = HrEmployeesInShift::selectRaw("*,FORMAT(effect_from,'yyyy-MM-dd') as effect_from")->with('HrEmployeeShiftMaster')->where('status',1)->where('deleted_at',NULL)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

How can I ensure that the effect_from date field is displayed and used in the correct format ("Y-m-d") when retrieved from the database in Laravel? Is there any configuration or conversion step that I might be missing?

**In windows it's working perfectly. Only this issue happening in Linux OS**

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share  your model? Usually you need to declare which model properties other than `created_at` and `updated_at` are dates via [date casting](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

Comment: "I have checked the database table and confirmed that the effect_from field is stored in the correct format." - dates are stored in a 4-byte binary structure in the database. The displayed string format is controlled entirely by the application.

Comment: Are you converting a datetime to a string  somewhere ?  For example  Select convert(varchar(50),getdate())  returns  Jun 19 2023  3:00PM

Comment: Even an implicit conversion will produce the results ...  select concat('',getdate())

Comment: @apokryfos
I updated my model in the question. please check. It is normaly working in Windows. datetime field also working perfectly in both OS. only date field have issue. There  are many models I have the same issue. I just given one model here

Comment: @JohnCappelletti No. Iam directly calling the field using model

Comment: You say it's working fine in Windows but not in Linux. Are they accessing the same database instance, or has the database been copied from one system to another? The database rows you showed have a date column, but the values are a modified date/time column, which makes me wonder if it's a copy/dump issue.

Comment: @aynber Actualy I took a backup database from MSSQL and Restored in Azure Data Studio in ubuntu. Also same copy of code folder I took from my windows server.

Comment: Is the screenshot you're showing from MSSQL or is it from Azure?

Comment: @aynber it's azure. See the format is Y-m-d.

Comment: Have you tried https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting ? In the absense of that the format will not be controlled by Laravel but by the database connection driver and it would appear that it behaves differently between OSs

Comment: @apokryfos I tried this casting method and it wouldn't work for me. But actual I want to know why this is happening ?. and is there any configuration to change in Ubuntu or laravel

Comment: Just curious, try `DB::table('hr_employees_in_shift')->find(3465);` and see what the results are. Also try `DB::select('select id, effect_from, effect_to  from hr_employees_in_shift where id = 3465');`, just to bypass Eloquent and get the raw results from the database. You can try it in `php artisan tinker` directly to get an instant response.

Comment: @aynber 

`DB::table('hr_employees_in_shifts')->find(3465)

= {#11378
    +"id": 3465,
    +"employee_shift_master_id": 231,
    +"employee_id": "832",
    +"created_at": "2023-06-12 11:02:41",
    +"updated_at": "2023-06-12 11:02:41",
    +"deleted_at": null,
    +"employee_company_info_id": 343,
    +"effect_from": "Jun 13 2023 12:00:00:AM",
    +"effect_to": "Jun 30 2023 12:00:00:AM",
    +"created_by": 481,
    +"updated_by": null,
    +"deleted_by": null,
  }`

Tinker Result also same

Comment: Odd, so definitely not an Eloquent issue. At a guess, it may be something with pdo_sqlsrv or Azure's locale settings. One way to fix it might be to [cast those two columns as date](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)